# Urls in database

Tags: java, sql-server, web-services, shiro

We have a little problem with Apache Shiro.
We are using Shiro with a JDBC realm: users, roles, and permissions are stocked in our SQL server database. 
We have a java application used as a backoffice to insert, update or delete users, roles and permissions. But we need to do the same with Urls filters.

I found a few things about it, but i'm really a beginner with Shiro and i don't understand them, and often, the examples are whith servlets and JSP (we are only using HTML/CSS/JS and data are collected with web services).

Is anybody can explain how to stocked urls and filter in a database, and not in an INI file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shiro uses a default implementation of the [FilterChainManager](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/mgt/FilterChainManager.html) interface to manage and create Filters.  You could create a custom implementation of this interface to delegate to your database for config information.  See the [DefaultFilterChainManager](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shiro/trunk/web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/mgt/DefaultFilterChainManager.java) implementation for ideas.

Here's how this stuff works at runtime:

1. When a request comes in to the servlet container, it is intercepted by the `ShiroFilter`.
2. The ShiroFilter delegates to a [FilterChainResolver](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/mgt/FilterChainResolver.html) to acquire the `FilterChain` that should execute for any given request.
3. The default `FilterChainResolver`, a [PathMatchingFilterChainResolver](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shiro/trunk/web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/mgt/PathMatchingFilterChainResolver.java) implementation in turn inspects the request path and uses that to perform a lookup with the `FilterChainManager`.
4. The resolved FilterChain is returned and then executed by the master `ShiroFilter`.

You can plugin any `FilterChainResolver` you wish into the `ShiroFilter`.  You can use the default `FilterChainResolver` and have it delegate to your custom `FilterChainManager` instance, or you can implement either (or both) interfaces as your needs may require.

Comment: Ok. This is kind of hard for me, but i will watch it and probably looking for examples.

Comment: How exactly can I plugin custom `FilterChainResolver` to `ShiroFilter` ?